# jQuery preventDefault stops autocomplete from working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Has anyone else run into the issue where handling a click event on a submit button for a form with preventDefault stops autocomplete from working?

To be specific it simply never prompts to save the username and password combination, I assume this is because it is triggered on a post request which doesn't occur in my case.

Can anyone think of a workaround?

PS: I have only tested in IE but am willing to bet I will see similar issues in the other browsers (will test shortly).

Comment: Start using a real browser (Firefox, Chrom[e|ium], Opera) as your main browser and use IE only to test if your - standards-conforming - code also works in there. Btw, IE9 might also qualify as a "real browser" but well.. not released yet. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options when altering the flow of an event:

1. `e.preventDefault()`
2. `e.stopPropagation()`
3. `return false` (calls both of the above).

Maybe trying using `e.stopPropagation()` instead, and see what that does for you.